How should I handle a part with instrument changes in LilyPond?
I have a piece with six parts — recorders AATTBGb, except that the second alto part doubles soprano. At several points, the Alto Recorder 2 player switches to Soprano Recorder and back. The Alto parts are written in treble clef and the Soprano part in treble^8. There are multiple bars of rest for each switch.
I am producing both a score and parts. In the score, I would like separate staves — Soprano, Alto 1, Alto 2, and then the rest. The Alto 1 and Alto 2 parts are in a StaffGroup.
In the combined A2/S part, I would like:

At each entrance after an instrument change, a clef change and a box with the name of the new instrument.
Before each instrument change, after the last note played by the prior instrument, a box with “To ”.
At the top of each page, including the first, a box with the name of the current instrument.

None of the above should be in the score.
I searched for examples of how to do this and was surprised that I couldn't find any. I've been trying on my own with some success, but I could use advice from an expert user. (I would describe myself as intermediate. I don't mind writing a bit of Scheme, but I don't know much about LilyPond's internals.)
Currently, I have the Soprano and Alto 2 notes in separate variables, which works well in the score. I'm using \partCombine for the parts, but I keep running into problems and trying to patch over them. I have also considered combining the notes, but then I'm not sure how to split them apart for the score.
Is there a best practice for this?

Related: Doubling part's staves in LilyPond

"None of the above should be in the score": traditionally, at least for clarinets, horns, and so on in the orchestral context, all of that would be in the score, on a single staff for the doubling player.  Scoring it as you propose is more likely to cause confusion.

See for example the second movement of Lucia Corini's Suite for 5 Recorders at https://imslp.org/wiki/Suite_for_5_Recorders_(Corini%2C_Lucia)

For the simpler parts (in this case the basses), you’ll only need to make one Staff macro each.
For the other parts though, you’ll need a different Staff for the full score’s \score block and the parts’s \score block.  In this case, you should put the notes in a macro of their own, so that it can be called in each.
What you’re trying to do with the Alto 2 / Soprano part is a bit complicated, but using the \partCombine function (as you suggest) seems to work.  This has the advantage that you can use the inbuilt soloText, and soloIIText to show the new-instrument markup automatically.
Put the other instructions into macros of their own, and use a \tag  around instructions that don’t you want in the full score.
Put each instrument/group in the full score’s \score block, and filter out the parts-only tag with a call to \removeWithTag.
Make individual \score blocks for the players’ parts.

Notes:

I’m using a global Dynamics to store: tempi, time signatures, barlines,  line breaks, etc.  I know this isn’t really what this context is for, but it works.

I’m using the \transpose function for the various octave clefs because I find it easier to type the notes this way.  Remove these if you’d prefer to enter them at sounding pitch.


Code
\version "2.24.1"

\language "english"

%%%% GLOBAL
global = {
    \new Dynamics {
        \tempo 4=120
        \time 4/4
            s1*2 | \bar "||" %\break
            s1*2 | \bar "||" %\break
            s1*2 | \bar "|."
    }
}

%%%% RECORDERS

%% Alto 1
altoOne = {
    \new Staff {
        \set Staff.instrumentName = "Alto 1"
        \clef "treble"
            f'4 4 4 4 | R1 |
            f'4 4 4 4 | R1 |
            f'4 4 4 4 | R1 |
    }
}

%%% Alto 2 / Soprano

%% Change Markup
toSoprano = \tag #'partOnly { <>^\markup { \box { "To Soprano" } } }
toAltoTwo = \tag #'partOnly { <>^\markup { \box { "To Alto 2" } } }

%% Alto 2 notes
altoTwoNotes = {
        \clef "treble"
            f'4 g' a' b' | \toSoprano R1 |
            R1*2 |
        \clef "treble"
            g''4 a'' b'' c''' | R1 |
}

%% Soprano notes
sopranoNotes = {
        \transpose c c' {
            R1*2 |
        \clef "treble^8"
            c'4 d' e' f' | \toAltoTwo R1 |
            R1*2 |
        }
}

%% Soprano score
soprano = {
    \new Staff {
        \set Staff.instrumentName = "Soprano"
        \clef "treble^8"
            \sopranoNotes
    }
}

%% Alto 2 score
altoTwoScore = {
    \new Staff {
        \set Staff.instrumentName = "Alto 2"
        \clef "treble"
            \altoTwoNotes
    }
}

%% Alto 2 / Soprano part
altoTwoSoprano = {
    \new Staff {
        \set Staff.instrumentName = "Alto 2 / Soprano"
        \set Staff.soloText = \markup { \box { "Alto 2" } }
        \set Staff.soloIIText = \markup { \box { "Soprano" } }
            \partCombine
                \altoTwoNotes
                \sopranoNotes
    }
}

%% Altos 1, 2 score
altos = {
    \new StaffGroup {
        \set StaffGroup.systemStartDelimiter = #'SystemStartSquare
            <<
                \altoOne
                \altoTwoScore
            >>
    }
}

%%% Tenors

%% Tenor 1 notes
tenorOneNotes = {
            a'2 2 | R1 |
            a'2 2 | R1 |
            a'2 2 | R1 |
}

%% Tenor 2 notes
tenorTwoNotes = {
            c'2 2 | R1 |
            c'2 2 | R1 |
            c'2 2 | R1 |
}

%% Tenors 1, 2 score
tenors = {
    \new Staff {
        \set Staff.instrumentName = "Tenors 1, 2"
        \clef "treble"
            \partCombine
                \tenorOneNotes
                \tenorTwoNotes
    }
}

%% Tenor 1 part
tenorOne = {
    \new Staff {
        \set Staff.instrumentName = "Tenor 1"
        \clef "treble"
            \tenorOneNotes
    }
}

%% Tenor 2 part
tenorTwo = {
    \new Staff {
        \set Staff.instrumentName = "Tenor 2"
        \clef "treble"
            \tenorTwoNotes
    }
}

%% Bass score and part
bass = {
    \new Staff {
        \set Staff.instrumentName = "Bass"
        \clef "bass^8"
        \transpose c c' {
            f,1 | R1 |
            f,1 | R1 |
            f,1 | R1 |
        }
    }
}

%% Great Bass score and part
greatBass = {
    \new Staff {
        \set Staff.instrumentName = "Great Bass"
        \clef "bass^8"
        \transpose c c' {
            c,1 | R1 |
            c,1 | R1 |
            c,1 | R1 |
        }
    }
}

%% PAPER
\paper {
    left-margin = 1\in
}

%%%% SCORE
\score {
    \removeWithTag #'partOnly
    <<
        \global
        \new StaffGroup {
            <<
                \soprano
                \altos
                \tenors
                \bass
                \greatBass
            >>
        }
    >>
} %\pageBreak

%%%% PARTS

%% Alto 1
\score {
    <<
        \global
        \altoOne
    >>
} %\pageBreak

%% Alto 2 / Soprano
\score {
    <<
        \global
        \altoTwoSoprano
    >>
} %\pageBreak

%% Tenor 1
\score {
    <<
        \global
        \tenorOne
    >>
} %\pageBreak

%% Tenor 2
\score {
    <<
        \global
        \tenorTwo
    >>
} %\pageBreak

%% Bass
\score {
    <<
        \global
        \bass
    >>
} %\pageBreak

%% Great Bass
\score {
    <<
        \global
        \greatBass
    >>
}

